# SpringSecurity3.0 AuthenticationSuccessEvent cannot be detected

Tags: spring-security

I want to prepare some data after user login system. After some google, I implemented a ApplicationListener to listen AuthenticationSuccessEvent:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationSuccessEvent;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class MyApplicationListener implements
            ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
            UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) event.getAuthentication()
                    .getPrincipal();
            System.out.println("Successed login:" + userDetails.getUsername());

        }

    }
```

I updated to Spring 3.0 RELEASE, and Spring Security 3.0.0.RC2. But I can never get called for AuthenticationSuccessEvent:( (I tried other event,  such as AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent, it worked).

I use my own authentication-manager and do nothing about the event:

Do I need to podcast the event by myself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify the details of your configuration. You state that you use your own authentication-manager - does this mean you are configuring the `ProviderManager` explicitly using Spring Bean configuration?

If so, you need to configure the `AuthenticationEventPublisher` on the `ProviderManager`, as the default implementation is a null implementation, which doesn't publish events.

The bean declaration for the default implementation is like this:

```
<bean id="defaultAuthEventPublisher" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher"/>
```

You'll then need to map this bean to the appropriate property on the `ProviderManager`:

If you aren't declaring your own `ProviderManager`, unfortunately there is not a way to enable this functionality using the security namespace style of configuration. Hope that answers your question!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Spring-Security 2.0.4, but I think it's pretty the same.
From what that I saw the ProviderManager is the one that publish the event in case of successful authentication.

Few questions that might help:

1. Do you use the standard ProviderManager (org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager) or supply one of your own?
2. Maybe the @Component doesn't work?, maybe (just for testing) you can try the regular addListener() function.

The best way to understand what happens is to Ito debug Spring security (locate a break point in ProviderManager), I use to do it a lot and find it pretty useful.

Shay

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to listen for the InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent. OpenID for example emits that event only. See also [SEC-1534](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1534).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I found a few things that might help.

1. I think that we should include the following listener in web.xml

   ```
   <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
   ```
2. If you wonder if your problem is in the listener detection or the publising you may tray to lauch events yourself.

   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
   AuthenticationSuccessEvent event = new AuthenticationSuccessEvent(
   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
   eventPublisher.publishEvent(event);